# Show Offscreen Object / Target Indicator in Reality Kit

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I would like to have an indicator to let users know there is an AR object off screen (as suggested in the [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/system-capabilities/augmented-reality/)). How would I do this in RealityKit?

Answer (score 0):

You can use edge of the screen and add some icons(using swiftui or uikit) to let the user know that by orienting the device to that direction they will find a object.

Comment: a code snipet should be provided in order to fix it
otherwise you are asking for free work